# Biharmonic equation

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, differential-equations, elliptic-pde, regularity

Let us consider for $0<\alpha\leq V(x)\leq \beta$ and $0\leq K(x)<\gamma$ the equation
\begin{equation}\label{\star}
\Delta^2u+V(x)u=g(x, u)+K(x)u,
\end{equation}
where $|g(x,s)|\leq \varepsilon|s|^{1+\sigma}+c|s|^{p}$ with $1<\sigma<p<\frac{N+4}{N-4}$ and $s\geq 0.$

Is the solution $u$ of equation above in ${H}^4(\mathbb{R}^N)?$

Comment: the potential has: $0<a\leq V(x)\leq b$

Comment: You should include assumptions about $V$ and  $K$ in your problem. Including assumptions about $V$ is not okay. Also in the condition for $g$ you have $g(s)$ while in the problem $g$ depends on two variables. Correct it.

Comment: I included. Thank you Piotr Hajlasz.

Comment: If it is possible, it would also be good if you could add context of your question.

Comment: I'm searching by regularity of solutions for this nonlinear schrodinger equation in whole space